# Sorting records and then using updateMany in MongoDB with limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to update all records in my MongoDB database. I want to sort the records based on a date(updatedAt) in the ascending order. And then update a limited number of records based on its current-status(currentStatus).

This is how the fields are: 
[image]

I tried this but didn't work:

```
var count = 20;
var sortUpdatedAt = this.collection.find({}).sort({"updatedAt":1});
try {
    this.collection.updateMany(sortUpdatedAt,
     {"currentStatus": {$in:["ACTIVE","IDLE"]} },
     { $set: { "currentStatus" : "SHUTDOWN" } }
    ).limit(count);
} catch (e) {
    logger.error(e);
}
```

created the variable sortUpdatedAt because I read updateMany does not support .sort()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `find` and `updateMany` are not the right tools for this job. Instead, you should look into the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). Through the combination of [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/), [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) aggregation operators you should be able to do the exact operations described in the question.

PS: Don't forget to add an index to the field you are sorting (if you haven't already) in order to improve performance if this is intended to be a common operation to your collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last acceptable updatedAt and use it as a parameter in update query:

```
// done inside async context
var count = 20;
var lastAcceptable = await this.collection
  .find({
    currentStatus: { $in: ["ACTIVE", "IDLE"] }
  })
  .sort({ updatedAt: 1 })
  .limit(count);
var lastElement = lastAcceptable.pop();
try {
  this.collection.updateMany(
    {
      currentStatus: { $in: ["ACTIVE", "IDLE"] },
      updatedAt: { $lte: lastElement.updatedAt }
    },
    { $set: { currentStatus: "SHUTDOWN" } }
  );
} catch (e) {
  logger.error(e);
}
```